# Name of a special multivariate polynomial: each varaible appears alone

Tags: polynomials

Is there a name for such multivariate polynomial where each varaible appears alone. For example:

$P(x,y,z)=x+x^2+3x^3+y+5y^2+z +2$

So as it can be seen there is no terms in the polynomial  where the variables are multiplied by each other like  $xy$ or  $xz^2$ for instance.